# How can find the total of each row values in a ListView (rows were added using arrayList.add())

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm a beginner to Android Studio that's why I'm asking for a "little" help :D

I have this mini project that calculates the sum of each selected product...

The page contains two listViews... the first one contains all the products and the other one contains the prices of the selected products...

[image]

Here's my code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DisplayProduct extends Activity {
    ListView listViewOrder;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_product);
        BackgroundTask bTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        bTask.execute("get_info");

        listViewOrder = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.display_listviewAdded);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayProduct.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listViewOrder.setAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lvProductList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.display_listview);
        lvProductList.setClickable(true);

        lvProductList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProd_price);
                String text = tv.getText().toString();
                arrayList.add(text);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Well, my problem is... I don't really know how can I find the total of the prices using onClick button.

If you could provide me a sample code I would really really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have wrong naming conventions, which list view is for the prices selected

Comment: @Idee I named it listViewOrder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using your own model to store your data and populate `ListView` instead of taking `String` value from your `TextView`. Create something like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String title;
    private float price;
    private String category;

}
```

After that, create custom Adapter for your `ListView` which takes list of your `MyObject` 's and populate it.

At the end on your onClick method you can make something like this:

```
float total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++){
    MyObject myObject = myList.get(i);
    total += myObject.getPrice(); // create getter in your MyObject class
}

Log.d("TAG", "Total price is: " + total);
```

Doing this you will learn basic stuff which you will need to create in every project you working on, believe me! Try to do it and if you have any questions just ask.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much sir!